# Problemas con ReactJS y Webpack para uso de imágenes

Tags: reactjs, webpack

en mi `webpack.config.js`

```
{
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { 
                    limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                    name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                } 
            }]
        },
```

y mi componente

```
import React from 'react';
import auroraImagen from './../imagenes/aurora.jpg';
var envoltura = {
    backgrounImage: 'url(' + auroraImagen + ')'
};
const Hogar = () => {
    return(<div 
        style={envoltura}
        className='hogar-contenedor'>
        <h2 className='hogar__titulo'
        >Bienvenido a casa.</h2>
        <image >

        </image>

    </div>);
}; export default Hogar;
```

pero no renderiza la imagen el fondo, las imagenes estan guardadas en `src/imagenes/`

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque en 'webpack.config.js' en 'name' dice "images" y no "imagenes" ?

La otra que se me ocurre es que sea porque el path relativo de las imágenes en el componente no está llegando a la ruta real de las imágenes.

Cual es el path absoluto del componente y de las imágenes?

Comment: .hogar-contenedor {
    background-color: lightslategray;
    height: 60rem;
    margin-top: -45px;
    background-image:url(./../imagenes/aurora.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

Comment: las imagenes se encuentran en src/imagenes/aurora.jpg